# Search md5("cdef") in "abcdefgh"

Tags: search, hash, substring

I want to search a sub-string in a string, e.g. searching for 'cdef' in 'abcdefgh'. But I need to preprocess the sub-string using a certain algorithm in order to hide it so that nobody knows i search it. Just take md5() for example. So which is the fastest way to search for md5('cdef') in 'abcdefgh'?

Comment: Are you married to md5 for this, or will any transformation that makes the search string non-obvious work (e.g., rot13)?

Comment: I don't have to use md5. You get the point. I just want to make the search string non-obvious. Is there any other approaches to get this done?

Comment: Sure - if you use some form of reversible encryption, the problem is easy (particularly if it's as trivial as rot13 ;-P) - just decrypt the string before searching! If you post a new question with details on what you're trying to prevent, folks will be able to give you better (and more specific) ideas - how much work you put into this would depend mostly on how determined you expect the observers you're looking to thwart to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this for two reasons.

1. At a high level, the entire point of having a cryptographic hash function is to conceal the contents of the original string while giving others a way of confirming that the original string hashes to the correct value. Cryptographic hashes (even though MD5 is now broken) have the property that even minor tweaks to the input string cause huge changes to the output of the hash, so there should be no correlation between the MD5 of a substring and the string itself. If it was possible to determine whether a string, after hashing, was a substring of another, it would be a *huge* security breach and would completely invalidate the hash.
2. Multiple strings can have the same hash code, which means that if you just have the MD5 of a string, there's no possible way to know whether the original string is a substring of some other string. You could never distinguish the cases where you have the MD5 of a substring or the MD5 of a non-substring that coincidentally happens to have the same hash as the substring.

You'll need to fundamentally change your approach to get this to work.

Hope this helps!